# How to annotate specific cells in a heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I just annotate the four corner cells?

```
for N in Nvals:
    for R in Rvals:
        filename = "data"
        filename += "-N" + str(N) + "-R0" + str(R)
        filename += ".txt"

        data = []
        with open(filename) as file:
            for line in file.readlines():
                #line = line.strip('"\'`(), False True \n')
                try:
                    value = float(line)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
                else:
                    data.append(value)

        data = np.array(data)
        mean.append(np.mean(data))
               
    mean = np.array(mean).reshape(11,10)

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.figure(figsize=(3,3), dpi=175)

    res=sns.heatmap(mean,square=True,
                norm=LogNorm(0.01, 100),
            annot=True,annot_kws={'size': 4},
            xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False,
            cbar = False,
            cmap="viridis_r")
    res.invert_yaxis()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seaborn's `heatmap` allows to explicitly give a 2D array to be used as annotations. For example, you can create a list of lists with all empty strings except at the corners:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

mean = 100 ** np.random.rand(11, 10)
plt.figure(1, figsize=(3, 3), dpi=175)

annot_values = np.full_like(mean, np.nan)
for i, j in [(0, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, -1)]:
    annot_values[i, j] = mean[i, j]
m, n = mean.shape
annot_values = [[f'{mean[i, j]:.2g}' if i in (0, m - 1) and j in (0, n - 1) else ''
                 for j in range(n)]
                for i in range(m)]
ax = sns.heatmap(mean, square=True,
                 norm=LogNorm(0.01, 100),
                 annot=annot_values, annot_kws={'size': 10}, fmt="s",
                 xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False,
                 cbar=False,
                 cmap="viridis_r")
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Note that each time you call `plt.figure()` you create a new figure. Therefore, it is recommended to combine the two calls into one, preventing the creation of an empty figure.

About `f'{mean[i, j]:.2g}'`:

- The `f` changes the string into a [formatted string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings).
- The parts inside `{}` are of the form `{value:format}` or just `{value}` (getting a default format) and will be replaced by a formatted text.
- The format specifications are part of a complete [mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), where `.2g` means a "general" format with `2` significant digits.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since I am nee can you please explain what does this mean f'{mean[i, j]:.2g}'